# how to set top border for bottom navigation bar in android as shown in image

Tags: android, android-layout, bottomnavigationview

[image]

is it possible to set top border for bottom navigation bar in android, if  possible tell me how we can do this, i am using the new bottom navigation view of android. 
**Here is my code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true">
                <include
                    android:id="@+id/gamebar"
                    layout="@layout/gamebar_layout"
                    />
                <include
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    layout="@layout/toolbar_layout" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <!-- Let's add fragment -->
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/app_bar_layout"
            android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_navigation"
            android:id="@+id/contentContainer"/>
        <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="56dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            app:itemBackground="@color/BottomNavigationBgColor"
            app:itemIconTint="@color/CelestialBlue"
            app:itemTextColor="@color/CelestialBlue"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_main" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: @FerdousAhamed: same answer is already been given by rafsanahmad007(by using view),but i appreciate your effort.

Comment: what is the current status of your problem?

Comment: @FerdousAhamed: i am looking for some xml attribute for setting the border, but i think it is not there..

Comment: Yes there is no attribute for setting top border. You have to create it by using other view/viewgroup.

Comment: If you don't want to use VIEW then you can do it by another way. See my updated answer. Thank you~

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can try this: add a `View` element above `BottomNavigationView`

```
<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="4dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_navigation"
    android:background="#000000"></View>

<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    app:itemBackground="@color/BottomNavigationBgColor"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/CelestialBlue"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/CelestialBlue"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_main" />
```

[image]

Comment: by View we can do this, but is any other way like inbuilt xml attribute for setting this border

Comment: From the [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomNavigationView.html) i didn't find any xml attribute

Answer (score 12):

1. Define a background drawable using XML:

   ```xml
   <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
       <item>
           <shape android:shape="rectangle">
               <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />
           </shape>
       </item>
       <item android:top="1dp">
           <shape android:shape="rectangle">
               <solid android:color="@color/colorWhite" />
           </shape>
       </item>
   </layer-list>
   ```
2. Use it as background with

   ```xml
   android:background="@drawable/myBackgroundBottomDrawer"
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You can add top border by creating a new `LinearLayout` with a `View` for top border and place `android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView` below top ber `View`.

**Here is the working code. Just update your XML as below:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/gamebar"
            layout="@layout/gamebar_layout"/>
        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            layout="@layout/toolbar_layout" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Bottom Navigation Layout-->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <!-- Top Border -->
        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="6dp"
            android:background="#FF0000"> 

        </View>

        <!-- BottomNavigationView -->
        <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="56dp"
            app:itemBackground="@color/BottomNavigationBgColor"
            app:itemIconTint="@color/CelestialBlue"
            app:itemTextColor="@color/CelestialBlue"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_main" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Let's add fragment -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_above="@id/layout_bottom_navigation"
        android:id="@+id/contentContainer"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**UPDATE:** If you don't use `View` then you can add attribute `android:layout_marginTop` to `android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView` and set background color to `android:background="#FF0000"` to `LinearLayout`.

```
<!-- Bottom Navigation Layout-->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#FF0000">

        <!-- BottomNavigationView -->
        <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="56dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
            app:itemBackground="@color/BottomNavigationBgColor"
            app:itemIconTint="@color/CelestialBlue"
            app:itemTextColor="@color/CelestialBlue"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_main" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Hope this will help you~

Answer (score 0):

Here is the fixed version of the latest answer's issue where the divider is slightly thin.

1. Define a background drawable using XML:

   ```xml
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:gravity="top">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <size android:height="1.0dip" />
                <solid android:color="@color/colorWhite" />
            </shape>
        </item>
    </layer-list>
   ```
2. Use it as background with

   ```xml
    android:background="@drawable/bottom_navigation_view_background"
   ```